# Why creating objects in preallocated memory slow than creating objects with allocating memory for each object individually?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have a memory pool which represents as list of free memory chunks and i need use this chunks in "placement new" because storing objects in preallocated memory, may be faster than allocating memory for each object individually.

I have two code snippet which creating objects using "new" keyword.

First code snipped: objects created in preallocated memory with "placement new" using memory which provided by memory pool. 
Second code snipped: objects creating without using preallocated memory, just with "new".

Why snipped based on placement new slow than snipped without placement new?

**First snipped:**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

struct list
{
    list *next;
};

class Test
{
    public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

void* getPtr()
{
    static int init = 0;
    static list *head;
    static list *free;
    if (!init) {
        std::cout << "Initialized." << std::endl;
        init = 1;
        list *head = reinterpret_cast<list*>(new char(sizeof(Test)));
        free = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            head->next = reinterpret_cast<list*>(new char(sizeof(Test)));
            head = head->next;
        }
    }

    list *ret = free;
    free = ret->next; 
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    getPtr();
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
         new(getPtr())Test();
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-begin).count()<<" ns"<< std::endl;
}
```

**Second snipped**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
         new Test();
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-begin).count()<<" ns"<< std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us your exact compiler version and compilation command. Note that the performance of unoptimized/debug builds is completely meaningless. Also note that clang optimizes  away the entire loop of the second example.

Comment: You want to have a look at some learning material on doing micro benchmarks in C++, for example [this talk](https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk). It's harder than one might think.

Comment: I use gcc compiler http://rextester.com/DOS20329

Comment: I can't see any alignment logic here.

Comment: compiler version is 4.9.3

Comment: new char(sizeof(Test)) - don't you mean new char[sizeof(Test)]?

Comment: @JoeJoe Doing benchmarks in an online IDE is also a bad idea as you cannot control the hardware load and don't know the general setup.

Comment: @BaummitAugen the first one primes the "big nested loop" prior to starting the timer. That apparently-useless `getPtr()` all by its lonesome is there for precisely that. latedevelper's notation of improper sizing, is a helluva bug, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah sorry, messed that up. All that indirection in `getPtr` does look fishy though.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Oh, make no mistake, I concur completely. The code is hideous; I was just mentioning that horrid loop of loops isn't an integral part of the timing fiasco =P

Comment: @WhozCraig My comment was still wrong though, so thanks for pointing that out. Nevertheless, I guess the answer to this question is still "Your measurement is invalid". So OP, learn how to do a proper micro benchmark if you care about that stuff, as I said, it's harder than it looks.

Comment: @latedevelope yes, thank you. But it`s not fixed a problem

Comment: I don't know where you are getting your numbers, for me the first snippet is about 10 times faster (after changing char(...)->char[...])

Comment: For me, first one (pool) 407292500 ns, second one (new) 1505069300 ns. so first is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

I've never written a memory pool before but I think you'll want to take account of (at least) 3 things:

1. memory alignment
2. destructing allocated objects when the pool goes out of scope.
3. the return value of in-place `new`

I've attempted this here and written an equivalent test

```
struct destroy_not_free
{
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T* p) const { p->~T(); }
};

template<class Jobbie>
struct memory_pool {
    using buffer_type = std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Jobbie), alignof(Jobbie)>;

    memory_pool(std::size_t limit)
            : memptr_(std::make_unique<buffer_type[]>(limit)), limit_(limit), used_(0)
    {
        allocated_.reserve(limit);
    }

    memory_pool(const memory_pool&) = delete;
    memory_pool(memory_pool&&) = default;
    memory_pool& operator=(const memory_pool&) = delete;
    memory_pool& operator=(memory_pool&&) = delete;

    template<class...Args>
    Jobbie *create(Args &&...args) {
        if (used_ < limit_) {
            auto candidate = new(std::addressof(memptr_[used_])) Jobbie(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            allocated_.emplace_back(candidate);
            ++ used_;
            return candidate;
        }
        else {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }
    }


    // NOTE: order important. We want the vector of unique_ptr to 
    // be destroyed before the memory buffer otherwise calling the
    // destructors will result in software armageddon

    std::unique_ptr<buffer_type[]> memptr_;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Jobbie, destroy_not_free>> allocated_;
    std::size_t limit_;
    std::size_t used_;
};

class Test {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    {
        auto pool = memory_pool<Test>(10000000);
        auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            pool.create();
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "with memory pool: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test>> v;
        v.reserve(10000000);
        auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            v.emplace_back(new Test());
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "with new        : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

results on 3yr old imac compiled with apple clang 8, -O2:

```
with memory pool: 59 ms
with new        : 842 ms
```

Comment: Upvoted, but just to answer OP's question. OP's implementation is slower because it didn't pre-allocate the entire buffer, it's still allocating memory for one object at a time then calls placement new. This solution, pre-allocates therefore faster.

Comment: @TonyJ The OP's pool implementation_isn't_ slower, despite what he said, it's faster.

Comment: @latedeveloper OP's implementation is also wrong, so his measurement is irrelevant. Providing a correct implementation, and explaining why it's faster is much more helpful.

Comment: @TonyJ I corrected the OP's code - it's still faster. Your explanation of why it is slower is not correct.

Comment: @latedeveloper, I don't have much experience with memory pool's, but I have never seen a implementation of memory pool that doens't pre-allocate memory. So If you say OP's implementation is a memory pool, then I just have to disagree with you on how memory pool should be implemented.

Comment: @TonyJ The OP's code does pre-allocate memory, albeit not entirely correctly.